# C# email address combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox which contains address of mail recipients. When it's dropped down user sees a list of all addresses he ever sent a mail. I want combobox to append address in it's Text field instead of replacing all Text there.

So for example, I have a list of emails aaa@mail.com, bbb@mail.com, ccc@mail.com in combobox's list and aaa@mail.com is in combobox.Text. When I select bbb@mail.com from cbox's list I want to combobox.Text to became "aaa@mail.com, bbb@mail.com" but Text just becames bbb@mail.com.

```
This is the combobox:
+----------------+                                     +----------------+
| aaa@mail.com |V|                                     | aaa@mail.com |V|
+----------------+                                     +----------------+
| aaa@mail.com   |                                     | aaa@mail.com   |
| bbb@mail.com   |    trying to select this brings     | bbb@mail.com   | 
| ccc@mail.com   |       which is not desired          | ccc@mail.com   |
+----------------+                                     +----------------+

When someone clicks on aaa@mail.com or bbb@mail.com or ccc@mail.com the editable field becomes that value. For example, after selecting bbb@mail.com it will become 
+----------------+
| bbb@mail.com |V|
+----------------+

I want combobox to append values and not just select them. So I want it to show
+------------------------------+
| aaa@mail.com, bbb@mail.com |V|
+------------------------------+

instead of just 
+----------------+
| bbb@mail.com |V|
+----------------+
```

I wrote this code(it's just a form with combobox, button and button, form's FormClosed event is set, button's Click event is set and combobox's events selectedIndexChanged and TextChanged are set) but it doesn't work as I expect.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cboxFrom.Tag = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.emailFrom) ? "" : Settings.Default.emailFrom;
        cboxFrom.Text = (string)cboxFrom.Tag;
        if (Settings.Default.emailFroms == null)
            Settings.Default.emailFroms = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        //cboxFrom.DataSource = Settings.Default.emailFroms;
        foreach (string s in Settings.Default.emailFroms)
        cboxFrom.Items.Add(s);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void cboxFrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ComboBox cbox = (ComboBox)sender;
            string addr = (string)cbox.Items[cbox.SelectedIndex];
            if (addr != null && cbox.Tag != null && !(cbox.Tag as string).Contains(addr))
            {
                if (cbox.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
                    cbox.Text = addr;
                else
                    cbox.Text = cbox.Tag + ", " + addr;
                cbox.Tag = cbox.Text;
            }
            else
                cbox.Text = (string)cbox.Tag;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void cboxFrom_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cbox = (ComboBox)sender;
        cbox.Tag = cbox.Text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] addrs = cboxFrom.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach(string s in addrs)
        if(!Settings.Default.emailFroms.Contains(s.Trim()))
            Settings.Default.emailFroms.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to achieve, it seems very absurd

Comment: I want to append addresses instead of replacing them in editable field in combobox. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you append them on to a different control like a textbox, as this is confusing what will happen to bb@mail.com, will it disappear from the list or when clicked it appends again. This is not the way combobox is to be used in any case

Comment: I find it easier to screenshot the comboboxes than to make an ASCII version.

Comment: Does this help? 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/checkcombo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just have a suggestion here.

Instead of appending your comboBox text. Why don't you add a textBox and another button when clicked adds the selected email address from the comboBox to the textBox? Appending the textBox.Text property would be simpler to do, and it also allows the user to make sure that he has selected the correct email before adding it to the send list.

Doing it your way there are many email as I understand, and scrolling down users might make an erroneous selection and then it is automatically added to your comboBox.Text which the user cannot get out of.